# Getting distinct rows based on a certain field from a database in Django

Tags: sql, django, distinct

I need to construct a query in Django, and I'm wondering if this is somehow possible (it may be really obvious but I'm missing it...).

I have a normal query `Model.objects.filter(x=True)[:5]` which can return results like this:

```
FirstName    LastName    Country
Bob           Jones        UK
Bill          Thompson     UK
David         Smith        USA
```

I need to only grab rows which are distinct based on the `Country` field, something like `Model.objects.filter(x=True).distinct('Country')[:5]` would be ideal but that's not possible with Django.

The rows I want the query to grab ultimately are:

```
FirstName    LastName    Country
Bob           Jones        UK
David         Smith        USA
```

I also need the query to use the same ordering as set in the model's Meta class (ie. I can't override the ordering in any way).

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I only need the top five rows from the DB.

Comment: This is a tough one but I'm not sure that I'm fully understanding the question. Do you want the top five rows in which the country is distinct?

Comment: @S.Lott, slicing a queryset does not turn it into a list. Dx143 is correct that this is the way to just get the top 5 elements from the database.

Comment: Looks like there's a ticket for this:
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but it seems to me a dict should do the job, although ordering could be off then:

```
d = {}
for x in Model.objects.all():
    d[x.country] = x

records_with_distinct_countries = d.values()
```

Comment: This same thing can be performed with capturing the values in a `set`.

Comment: Not really. The countries can be put in the set as they are immutable. But the models are definitely not immutable, so can't be in a set. That's why I use a dict, the immutable country as key, and the record as value. I happen to use the dict keys as a set (which it conceptually is) without losing the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
countries = [f.country in Model.objects.all()]

for c in countries:
    try:
        print Model.objects.filter(country=c)
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that @skrobul is on the right track, but a little bit off.

I don't think you'll be able to do this with a single query, because the `distinct()` method adds the `SELECT DISTINCT` modifier to the query, which acts on the entire row.  You'll likely have to create a list of countries and then return limited QuerySets based on iterating that list.

Something like this:

```
maxrows = 5
countries = set([x.country for x in Model.objects.all()])
rows = []
count = 0
for c in countries:
    if count >= maxrows:
        break

    try:
        rows.append(Model.objects.filter(country=c)[0])
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    count += 1
```

This is a very generic example, but it gives the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the raw SQL that returns what you want from the source database?  I have a hunch that the actual problem here is the query/data structure...