# select objects based on a distinct value in django

Tags: django, orm, distinct

I have a list of different Wall posts, each wallpost containing one object. Two wall posts may reference the same object.

It goes like this:

```
   class Object(models.Model):
        #stuff

   class WallPost(models.Model):
       #stuff
       object = ForeignKey(Object)
```

Now I want to select Wallposts that only contain different objects. I would like to do something like this:

```
   WallPost.objects.distinct('object__id')
```

But distinct does not take any parameters so such thing is not possible.

So maybe using values:

```
  WallPost.objects.values('object__id').distinct()
```

This gives me a list of distinct objects but I don't want Object ids, I want WallPost ids.
So maybe:

```
   Wallpost.objects.values('object__id').distinct().values('pk')
```

I expect this to give me a list of wallpost ids related to distinct objects. But this does not work.

Comment: WallPost.objects.all().distinct() not working?

Comment: Please, post some data samples.

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784672/getting-distinct-rows-based-on-a-certain-field-from-a-database-in-django

Comment: @DenisKabalkin: WallPost.objects.all().distinct() gives distinct wall posts. Two WallPosts containing the same object are distinct.
But I don't want that, I want only wallposts with different object ids.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes this is exactly the same issue as mine, I didn't see it earlier. But it remains unsolved, except by manipulated the query results manually in python.

Comment: I don't think there's a way you're going to be able to do what you want within a single or chained ORM call. I would go the manual route.